# Bootstrap Column Ordering: On mobile, ordering three columns as two above one

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

The scenario is:

```
[A][B][C]
```

When I move to XS, I want to order:

```
[A][C]
[B]
```

Is this possible with the following structure? Do I need to rearrange?

```
<div class="col-sm-3">A</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">B</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">C</div>
```

Comment: B underneath A and C or just underneath A ?

Comment: @Put12co22mer2 That's just a matter of changing the column size of `[B]` to match that of `[A]` instead of both `[A]` and `[C]`; it's under `[A]` regardless :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default in Bootstrap, if the column count is greater than 12 in a given row, any columns over the mark will be moved to a new row.

Also, you can set individual column sizes for each screen size by chaining the screen size class to a `<div>`.

With that being said, you could do something like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">A</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">B</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">C</div>
</div>
```

On small screens, this would display as:

```
[___][______][___]
```

And on extra small screens as:

```
[______][______]
[______________]
```

Feel free to adjust the column sizes to fit your needs, just be sure to have > 12 columns in the `<div class="row">` to force the extra column to push below.

Hope that helps!

**EDIT**

Bootstrap supports column reordering based on screen size, using the `col-X-pull-Y` classes (size, columns). So, a simple solution for this is:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">A</div>    
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-sm-push-6">C</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-3">B</div>
</div>
```

Notice the order has changed to accommodate the states at the lowest size, and I simply `push` and `pull` one column at any larger size to position them where they are needed.

Comment: This simply slots C underneath A and B. I need B underneath A and C.

Comment: Oh... Seems I missed that requirement. Gimme one sec, I think Bootstrap has a way to handle this, `col-push` and `col-pull` or something like that.

Comment: I had a feeling I needed to physically reorder the columns then push and pull, but I wasn't sure how. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Bootply** :  http://www.bootply.com/ziPH2ghaTB

**HTML** :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 a">a</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-sm-push-4 c">c</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-4 b">b</div>
</div>
```